# Swap [argo] with [argoproj]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently the [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo) tag means

> Apply to questions regarding thoughtbot's Swift JSON parser, Argo. For questions about the Kubernetes workflow tool, use [argoproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argoproj).

But the thing is, since Swift got its own native JSON parser, all others fell into obscurity.

The last time this tag was used for Argo the JSON parser [it was 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905411/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type).
Even the [library](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) had no updates since [May 22, 2020](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

On the other hand "Kubernetes workflow tool" (that currently should go under [argoproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argoproj)) is quite popular and active.

There're new kubernetes related questions with mismatched tag [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo) every month. The last on was [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72559298/argocd-unable-to-delete-application-resource-with-cascade) (before making this retag-request I tried to fix [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo) to [argoproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argoproj) in all kubernetes questions).

## Proposition

- Rename [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo) to something different like [argo-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo-swift), [argo-thoughtbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo-thoughtbot), [argo-json-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo-json-parser), etc.
- Rename [argoproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argoproj) to just [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo), to be used with Kubernetes workflow.

Comment: Please use tag-specific Markdown for denoting tags - they are autolinked and properly formatted. Use `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` for main and Meta tags respectively.

Comment: The problem is ambiguous tag names, so renaming argoproj to argo just repeats history. Something like kubernetes-argo then, perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

To reduce the ability for tag misuse, we should strive to name tags as unambiguously as possible, as well as make it very hard for users to blindly click on the first autocompletion result after typing the first few characters. In light of this, it is proposed to:

1. Rename [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo) to [swift-argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-argo) (note that the "swift" is prefixed — otherwise we are guaranteed, as unfortunate as it is, to get users typing "argo" and choosing the Swift one).
2. Rename [argoproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argoproj) to [kubernetes-argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-argo) as [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418629/swap-argo-with-argoproj#comment914508_418629) by [Gimby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/424903/gimby) in comments as, indeed, renaming it to [argo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argo) puts us at square one in terms of naming ambiguity.